# Bamana Sand Divination Python Program

Tags: python

I have an assignment that entails writing a Python program that replicates the geomancy practice of the Bamana.

---

- The first task to achieving this is to write a program that takes input as a single line of text.
- The line may consist of any number of spaces or dashes(-), but no other characters.
- Given this line, display whether there are an odd or even number of dashes.
- If there are an even number of dashes in the line, output 0.
- Otherwise, output 1.

---

This is the code I have written so far:

```
dashes = str(input())

mod = dashes % 2

if mod > 0:
    print("0")
else:
    print("1")
```

It isn't working so may someone please assist me?

Thank you.

Comment: How is it not working? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: Well I expected to get either 0 or 1 as my output, but instead, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the important point : the amount of dashes, use `str.count`

```
line = input("Enter a list of dashes: ")
nb_dashes = line.count("-")
mod = nb_dashes % 2
if mod > 0:
    print("0")
else:
    print("1")
```

---

Just so you know, you could use `bool => int` conversion to print 0 or 1

```
mod = nb_dashes % 2
print(int(mod == 0)) # True > 1, False > 0
```

Comment: This won't work if there are spaces in the input as it will also count the spaces as dashes.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modulo a string, which doesn't make any sense.

You should first get the number of dashes using `.count` method and then modulo that, plus `input` function in python 3 already returns a string so you don't need to convert it.

```
inp = input("Enter a list of dashes: ")
dashes = inp.count('-')
mod = len(dashes) % 2
if mod > 0:
    print("0")
else:
    print("1")
```